# Begin a flight itinerary with a transfer

Tags: air-travel, tickets, layovers, hong-kong

I'd like to fly to a hub (Hong Kong) on a budget airline with no partnerships. From there, I have just one hour to board the leg to Tokyo via ANA.

Both airlines are operating from the same terminal, so I should be able to walk from one gate to the other. Will I be fine showing up with just the boarding pass I printed from online check-in?

Checked luggage just ain't gonna happen, of course.

Comment: Given that a delay of only a few tens of minutes on the inbound leg could lead you to miss your onward flight, it sounds rather tight for a non-protected connection/transit to me

Comment: Yeah, I'm having strong doubts too. The other alternatives will still be similar, though. Even if I don't *need* to go back through security, I'd still rather not.

Comment: What is your specific question? Whether you are permitted to do this, without clearing security? If it is *wise* to do this (by some arbitrary definition of "wise")? Or something else?

Comment: @Flimzy Whether it is permitted. Is the DIY boarding pass really sufficient? Can I get from the arrival gate back to the departures area from an airline that doesn't typically serve transfers there? I've been through Hong Kong, and that gate area has plenty of huge monitors with all the gate assignments. Unless I'm breaking a rule, it should be pretty smooth.

Comment: What needs to be clarified? I imagine this is a pretty general problem for regional airports served by unaffiliated budget airlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is more of a general one, and it can be different for Hong-Kong. But **generally**, you are taking a huge risk but it is still permitted.

If you have only one ticket, then you should be totally fine. Airline will take care of your baggage if any, and if the first flight was delayed, they will compensate you and/or arrange alternative flights because. Note that it should be one ticket, and all flights should be under one PNR/E-Ticket number.

One World and such flight flight alliance can probably make things a little bit better (they take *some* responsibility if the flight was delayed, etc). Cathay Pacific (Hong-Kong based airline is in One World FYI). But again, this is not a really good point to ask the airline for alternative flights if your flight was delayed.

If you have separate tickets, then it becomes your responsibility if you no-show to the second flight. Given that you have only one hour, I would not do this if I was you. One hour is not enough time even for a domestic flight. Since it's the same terminal and you have no baggage, it's technically possible to do it, but once again, you are taking a big risk.

Make sure you have the boarding passes ready. 
If you do not have boarding passes, or need to check-out/in baggage, then you have to go through security, immigration and customs. There can be a lot of crowd in the passport checking counters, and you will probably need to walk a lot to go to the security and come to departure area.

Comment: Thanks. So, a boarding pass is a boarding pass, and the only risk I need to worry about is missing the connection.